# Can't connect to guest node set up with nat and hostonly vagrant and virtualbox

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have been trying to replace manual vitualbox setup with vagrant. I usually create a guest node with 2 network adapters a NAT for the guest(ubuntu) to use the host internet for all apt-get operations, and a hostonly for my host to connect to the guest. I has been working pretty well.

Below is my vagrant file

```
Vagrant.configure("1") do |config|
  config.vm.boot_mode = :gui
end

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
      web.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest:22, host:2222, id:"ssh", disabled:true 
      web.vm.network "private_network", ip:"192.168.56.103", :adapter =>2
    end

end
```

Below is the output:

```
Bringing machine 'web' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> web: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> web: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> web: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> web: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is available! You currently
==> web: have version '14.04'. The latest is version '20150430.0.0'. Run
==> web: `vagrant box update` to update.
==> web: Setting the name of the VM: ansible_web_1431424632866_64634
==> web: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> web: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> web: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    web: Adapter 1: nat
    web: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> web: Forwarding ports...
==> web: Booting VM...
==> web: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    web: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:22
    web: SSH username: vagrant
    web: SSH auth method: private key
    web: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    web: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    web: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

Now on vagrant it almost works and I can't figure out few things:
**Question 1** Does vagrant need port forwarding to connect to the guest?
**Question 2** When vagrant says : `==> web: Preparing network interfaces  based on configuration...
    web: Adapter 1: nat
    web: Adapter 2: hostonly` I figured the eth1 should be up but that's not the case. `ifconfig -a` shows the interface eth1 without any IP any `sudo ifup eth1` shows  `Ignoring unknown interface eth1=eth1`. What happened here and how can I solve this?

Thanks for helping

Comment: The situation could be because of VirtualBox failed to redirect ports, despite saying 
'**==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)**'
You may have a look at full description in my question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529651/virtualbox-nat-failed-to-redirect-tcp-127-0-0-12222-10-0-2-1522).
I still have no idea how to fix redirection fail(
Please drop a note in my post, if and how you succeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I fixed it. This relies heavily on the version of vagrant used. This works with any of the version which support auto correct feature of the forwarding port.

After removing the line:

```
web.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest:22, host:2222, id:"ssh", disabled:true
```

It started working like a charm and I could add other nodes .Kindly see below the config that worked for sake of sharing

```
Vagrant.configure("1") do |config|
  config.vm.boot_mode = :gui
end

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  auto_config= false

    config.vm.define "web" do |web|
       web.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
       web.vm.network "private_network", ip:"192.168.56.103", :adapter =>2
    end

   (1..3).each do |i|
      config.vm.define "mongo-#{i}" do |mongo|
         mongo.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
         mongo.vm.network "private_network" , ip:"192.168.56.11#{i}", :adapter =>2
     end
   end 

  (1..2).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "tomcat-#{i}" do |tomcat|
      tomcat.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
      tomcat.vm.network "private_network" , ip:"192.168.56.12#{i}", :adapter =>2
    end
  end

  (1..2).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "mysql-#{i}" do |mysql|
      mysql.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
      mysql.vm.network "private_network" , ip:"192.168.56.13#{i}", :adapter =>2
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: i've tried it, but still the error with port redirection. May be i have something wrong with os/config.

Comment: Which os are you using? You might want to check the combination of Os, virtualbox version and vagrant version. I have not done anything extra. It automatically picks its own port the subsequent times. I personally don't like port forwarding

Comment: The OS is windows 8.1. I don't like port forwarding too, but it's how it have to be.